# type ObjectQuery or DbQuery Error when updating a object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Below is the object

```
namespace TestingForCw2.Shared
{
   public class Dog
   {
       [Key]
       public Int32 Id { get; set; }
       public string DogName { get; set; }
       public Int32 DogAge { get; set; }
   }
}
```

This is the code for updating a Dog object in asyncrnous,

```
        public async Task<bool> UpdateDog(Dog dog)
        {
            try
            {
                await _appDbContext.Dog.Where(d => d.Id == dog.Id).UpdateAsync(d => new Dog
                {
                    DogName = dog.DogName
                    , DogAge = dog.DogAge
                });

                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Although for some reason i get the following error

Error : **The query must be of type ObjectQuery or DbQuery. (Parameter 'source')**

Hope someone can help me to fix this, thank you!

Comment: share your code not screenshot...

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN done, pls help me out now

Comment: Which EF version is this? Which line throws the exception? And what is `UpdateAsync`?

Comment: That said, if you use EF-core together with a library that talks about `ObjectQuery`, you have a library that expects EF for .net framework.

Comment: @GertArnold 5.0.12 is the EF version, and the error throws at the await line

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that it is because you're try to both query _appDbContext.Dog and update it at the same time.
My approach would be to first pull up the entity that I'm trying to change, change its props and then update it.

```
    public async Task<bool> UpdateDog(Dog dog)
    {
        Dog dogToUpdate = await _appDbContext.Dog.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Id == dog.Id);
        dogToUpdate.DogName = dog.DogName;
        dogToUpdate.DogAge = dog.DogAge;
        try
        {
            await _appDbContext.Dog.UpdateAsync(dogToUpdate);
            await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me, i get the error in the first await line, the error is highlighte on the dogToUpdate value saying "cannot convert from 'TestingForCw2.Shared.Dog' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TestingForCw2.Shared.Dog, TestingForCw2.Shared.Dog>>"

Answer (score 0):

```
        public async Task<bool> UpdateDog(Dog dog)
        {
            Dog dogToUpdate = await _appDbContext.Dog.FindAsync(dog.Id);
            dogToUpdate.DogName = dog.DogName;
            dogToUpdate.DogAge = dog.DogAge;
            try
            {
                await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

With the help of @JackZanardo logic, i basically removed the 'UpdateAsync' await line, and used FindAsync method.